# Transform without moving to the center

Tags: animation, manim

i tried to transform a number into other but it went to the center of the screen, but i wanted it to just transform a "1" into a "0", and having the same positioning

I already tried searching. And I tried to put the number "0" behind the number "1" but with zero opacity and when I transform the 1 become invisible

[What's happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxJ5g.gif)

[This is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kaiaf.gif) (but not in center)

Comment: Please post your code to make it easier to help you

Answer (score 1):

New objects are (with few exceptions) always created around the ORIGIN in Manim. In order to transition while keeping the placement you need to make sure that the new object is already at the same location as the old before the `self.play()` with the transformation.

You can do this e.g. by `new_object.move_to(old_object.get_center())` or when it comes to aligning the objects at different critical points `new_object.shift(old_object.get_critical_point(DL)-new_object.get_critical_point(DL))` which would make sure that the lower left corners of the objects align.

If you want to learn more about Manim join the Discord server: [Where can I find more resources for learning Manim?](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/faq/general.html?highlight=discord#where-can-i-find-more-resources-for-learning-manim)

Comment: ok, now it's solved the problem, tysm <3

Answer (score 0):

```py
class Manimation(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        zero = MathTex("0").to_corner(UL).shift(DR*0.8).scale(4)
        one = MathTex("1").move_to(zero.get_center()).scale(4)
        self.play(Write(zero))
        self.wait(0.5)
        self.play(Transform(zero, one))
        self.wait()
```

Sample code using what Uwezi mentioned.